# Como selecionar um elemento em uma seleção do jQuery

Tags: jquery

Por exemplo, tenho o seguinte código:

```
var $els = $('elementos'); // cerca de 8 elementos selecionados
```

Então desse grupo de elementos, quero um elemento que tenha a classe `active`. Tentei algo como:

```
$els.find('.active');
```

Porém não deu certo, porque o método `find` procura por elementos filhos. Não tentei o método `siblings` pois tenho mais de um elemento selecionado e eles não são necessariamente "irmãos".

Como encontrar um determinado elemento neste grupo e depois poder navegar entre eles como `next()` e `prev()`, é possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso você usa [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var $els = $('elementos');
var $el = $els.filter('.active');
```

Agora, se você navegar com `next` e `prev` a partir do `$el`, vai estar navegando pelos irmãos dele no DOM, não na sua lista original `$els`.

Comment: É verdade, tinha esquecido do `filter`. Pois então bfavaretto, eu já imaginava isso da navegação. Eu reparei que no objeto `$el` tem o objeto `prevObject` que é a lista anterior, se eu tiver o index do `$el` da pra fazer a navegação. Como pega-lo?

Comment: Olha só: https://jsfiddle.net/ndc1nryh/1/

Comment: Você volta pra lista anterior com o [`end`](https://api.jquery.com/end/) – https://jsfiddle.net/ndc1nryh/2/

Comment: Verdade. Adicionei uma resposta com essa parte, vou complementar...

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta, sobre como navegar entre os elementos:

Basta:

- Pegar o objeto anterior: <s>`$el.prevObject`</s> [`$el.end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/) (como mencionado pelo @bfavaretto)
- Pegar o índice do objeto selecionado: `$els.index($el)`
- <s>Navegar entre eles: `$el.prevObject[$els.index($el)-1]` ou `$el.prevObject[$els.index($el)+1]`</s>
- Navegar entre eles: `$el.end()[$els.index($el)-1]` ou `$el.end()[$els.index($el)+1]`

```js
$els = $('li');
$el = $els.filter('.active');


$prev = $( $el.end()[$els.index($el)-1] );
$next = $( $el.end()[$els.index($el)+1] );

$('.prev').text('Anterior: ' + $prev.text() );
$('.el').text( 'Ativo: '     +  $el.text()  );
$('.next').text( 'Próximo: ' + $next.text() );
```

```css
.active{
   color: #2376D0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>Item 1 1</li>
<li>Item 1 2</li>
<li>Item 1 3</li>
<li>Item 1 4</li>
<li>Item 1 5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="active">Item 2 1</li>
<li>Item 2 2</li>
<li>Item 2 3</li>
<li>Item 2 4</li>
<li>Item 2 5</li>
</ul>
<div class="prev"></div>
<div class="el"></div>
<div class="next"></div>
```

Comment: Eu acho que `prevObject` foi concebido como um método interno do jQuery, tanto que não consta da documentação.  Melhor usar o `end` mesmo.

Comment: E cuidado com o `index`, se não me engano ele retorna o índice do objeto em relação ao objeto pai no DOM, não em relação à sua seleção.

Comment: Atualizei o código, coloquei o primeiro elemento da segunda lista pra testar, e o objeto anterior selecionado foi o último da primeira lista. @bfavaretto